# Source of RST packet on ASA 5510

Tags: cisco-asa

In reference to previous posts such as
[Finding source of RST packet on ASA 5505](https://serverfault.com/questions/289476/finding-source-of-rst-packet-on-asa-5505)
I am not seeing any answers about how to FIX the RST from being sent by ASA; I only see discussion of how to provide a trace on the external interface to prove RST is coming from ASA.

What settings in ASA should I be reviewing to prevent RST in the first place? Desription of my setup: we have a VPN tunnel to a customer site and that customer has established a socket connection to one of our hosts. After a long period of idle time, when the customer sends data through the socket our ASA seems to issue RST. The RST does NOT come from our host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure `idle timeout` and `session timeout` as `none`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I accept your answer as correct, though unfortunately we can confirm idle and session timeouts were already set to 0. Our customer swears the RST comes from our ASA because they see encaps/decaps count increasing exactly with packet count. I tried to argue that RST could come from a different edge router, but they say the encaps/decaps count coinciding with RST packet count means RST is fully encapsulated and therefore comes from VPN headend.

Comment: Are you sure your host is not creating TCP RST?

Comment: You should really sniff the traffic going to the remote peer in the tuunel, and also coming from within inside peer. and see if TCP packet from the host comes with RST falg being "1".